# Grouping and moving remaining nodes using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <case>
      <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
   </case>
   <results>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey1</IKEY>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject1</OBJECTID>
      </row>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey1</IKEY>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject2</OBJECTID>
      </row>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey1</IKEY>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject3</OBJECTID>
      </row>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey4</IKEY>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject4</OBJECTID>
      </row>
   </results>
</response>
```

My requirement is to group all the matching `<IKEY>` rows and move them under one `<row>` and moving all `<OBJECTID>` nodes under that new `<row>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <case>
      <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
   </case>
   <results>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey1</IKEY>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject1</OBJECTID>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject2</OBJECTID>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject3</OBJECTID>
      </row>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey4</IKEY>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject4</OBJECTID>
      </row>
   </results>
</response>
```

I am trying with the following xsl for grouping based on `<IKEY>`, but I am not able to move all `<OBJECTID>` nodes to new `<row>`(Here I have to use only XSLT 1.0).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:key name="ikey" match="row" use="string(IKEY)" />
   <xsl:template match="results">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ikey', string(IKEY))[1])]" mode="ikey" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="row" mode="ikey">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="IKEY">
            <row>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="IKEY|OBJECTID" />
            </row>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can somebody tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
           <xsl:apply-templates select="IKEY|OBJECTID" />
```

to

```
           <xsl:apply-templates select="IKEY|key('ikey', IKEY)/OBJECTID" />
```

Comment: That's perfect! Plus One for quick response.